# Should I use MyISAM over InnoDB to save disk space?

Tags: innodb, myisam

I have a table that consists of an `int` primary key and `text` column and serving primarily in a "read" role. There are currently only about 40,000 rows, but in time, I expect there to be an additional 500,000 rows per year. This is on a system with perhaps 10 active users per day, so very low-impact.

With MyISAM, the table is less than 4MB. With InnoDB, it is over 7MB.

If disk space is a concern, is MyISAM really so untrustworthy that I should use InnoDB over MyISAM?

Comment: Its the year 2021 and you're worried about 3MB? Even at 10x that, it would be 30M. You aren't going to get saving of 30M of storage to counter any reliability failure. Use InnoDB.

Comment: Growth projections put us out to ~500MB to 1TB in five years.

Comment: And in 5 years you won't be able to buy a disk that is _only_ 1TB !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're worried about 3MB? er- don't.

Even at 10x that, roughly your expected increase, it would be 30M.

You aren't going to get saving of 30M of storage to counter any reliability failure.

Use InnoDB.

Comment: Is there any point in storage savings where you would be inclined to use MyISAM at all? Does 1TB give you any pause?

Comment: growth implies you are writing to it, and need durability.